# Confirm dialog in Tapestry

Tags: java, html, tapestry

I have very odd situation here where I can't set the fields because input is on clients side, and `onSuccess` function is called only after I press Confirm from mixin. Can't back, can't ahead.

I press Confirm and I get opened Confirm dialog. But because values here aren't yet set (they are waiting for Submit from the Confirm dialog) I get those values as null and 0. Can you propose me how to get rid of this situation. Also what troubles me also is that I can't click on Confirm button once I am in dialog mode and I have no clue why is that.

Thanks on your help.

```
       <t:layout t:pageTitle='${message:AddTickets}' xmlns:t="http://tapestry.apache.org/schema/tapestry_5_3.xsd">
        <t:jquery.jgrowl />
        <form t:type="form" t:id="dodajTiket">
            <t:zone t:id="zonaDjelovanja" id="zonaDjelovanja">
                <t:errors/>
                <div class="palette palette-concrete" style="height:80%;">

                    <div class="col-xs-12" style="margin-left:17px;">
                        <h5>${message:selectTypeOfTicket}</h5>
                        <t:select t:id="drawTip" style="color:black;" validate="required" t:event="OsvjeziZonu" zone="zonaDjelovanja" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- fecha del sorteo -->
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <t:label for="datum"><h6>${message:datum}</h6></t:label>
                            <t:datefield id="uzmiDatum" validate="required" class="form-control" t:id="datum"/>
                        </div>

                        <!-- no de fracciones -->
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="post-box"><label><h6>${message:numberOfTickets}</h6></label>
                                <input class="form-control" validate="required"  t:type="TextField" t:id="brojTiketa" t:value="brojTiketa"/></div>   
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="post-box"><label><h6>${message:number}</h6></label>
                                <input class="form-control" id="uzmiBroj" validate="required"  t:type="TextField" t:id="broj"/></div>   
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="post-box"><label><h6>${message:serial}</h6></label>
                                <input class="form-control" validate="required"  t:type="TextField" t:id="series" t:value="series" /></div>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <div class="post-box"><label><h6>${message:price}</h6></label>
                                <input class="form-control" t:type="TextField" t:id="cijena" t:value="cijena"/></div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <div class="col-xs-3">
                            <!--
                            <t:submit value="Confirmar" t:event="dodajTiket" class="form-control"  t:height="300" t:message="¿Seguro que desea crear esta entrada? ${kopijaBroj}" t:mixins="confirm"/>
                            -->
                            <t:zone t:id="zonaUploadovanja" id="zonaDjelovanja">
                                <div t:type="jquery/dialog" t:zone="zonaDjelovanja" t:clientId="modal-example" class="k-modal" t:params="params">
                                    <div class="content">

                                        <p>¿Seguro que desea crear esta entrada? 
                                        </p> 
                                        ${brojTiketa}
                                        <!--
                                            <script> document.getElementById('izmiBroj').value</script>-->
                                        <p style="color:red; font-size: 25px;">6</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <t:submit t:event="OsvjeziZonu" value="Confirmar" class="form-control" />
                                </div>
                            </t:zone>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </t:zone>
        </form>

        <t:jquery.dialoglink t:dialog="modal-example" class="k-modal-trigger">Open</t:jquery.dialoglink>
    </t:layout>
```

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package rs.domaci.pages;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ComponentResources;
import org.apache.tapestry5.EventConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.PersistenceConstants;
import org.apache.tapestry5.alerts.AlertManager;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Component;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.InjectComponent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.OnEvent;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Persist;
import org.apache.tapestry5.annotations.Property;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Form;
import org.apache.tapestry5.corelib.components.Zone;
import org.apache.tapestry5.hibernate.annotations.CommitAfter;
import org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.annotations.Inject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.json.JSONObject;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.ComponentSource;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.Request;
import org.apache.tapestry5.services.ajax.AjaxResponseRenderer;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import rs.domaci.entities.Tiket;
import rs.domaci.entities.TiketStatus;
import rs.domaci.entities.TipDrawTiketa;

/**
 * This page is for generating tickets!
 *
 * @author
 */
public class AddTickets {

    @Property
    private String drawNumberOfTicket;
    @Inject
    private Session hibernate;
    @Property
    private int series;
    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.CLIENT)
    private String datum;
    @Inject
    private ComponentSource componentSource;
    @Property
    // price
    private int cijena;
    @Property
    @Persist
    private String kopijaDatum;
    @Property
    @Persist
    private int kopijaBroj;
    /**
     * @Property private
     */
    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.CLIENT)
    private int broj;
    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private int brojTiketa;
    @Property
    private TiketStatus status = TiketStatus.DISPONIBLE;
    @InjectComponent
    private Zone zonaDjelovanja;
    @Inject
    private Request request;
    @Inject
    private AjaxResponseRenderer ajaxResponseRenderer;
    @Inject
    private ComponentResources componentResources;
    @Property
    @Persist(PersistenceConstants.FLASH)
    private TipDrawTiketa drawTip;
    @Inject
    private AlertManager manager;
    @Component(id = "dodajTiket")
    private Form form;

    // Generally useful bits and pieces
    void setupRender() {

        datum = null;
        updateDisplay(drawTip);
    }

//    public TipDrawTiketa getNAVIDENA() {
//        brojTiketa = 20;
//        return TipDrawTiketa.NAVIDENA;
//    }
//
//    public TipDrawTiketa getCHANCES() {
//        brojTiketa = 10;
//        return TipDrawTiketa.CHANCES;
//    }
//
//    public TipDrawTiketa getLOTERIANACIONAL() {
//        brojTiketa = 20;
//        return TipDrawTiketa.LOT_NAC;
//    }

    public String getFormatirajMe() {
        String prviDio = String.format("%03d", series);
        String drugiDio = String.format("%02d", broj);
        return prviDio + drugiDio;
    }

    public Object getOsvjeziZonu() {
        if (drawTip == drawTip.LOT_NAC) {
            brojTiketa = 20;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else if (drawTip == drawTip.CHANCES) {
            brojTiketa = 10;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else if (drawTip == drawTip.NAVIDENA) {
            brojTiketa = 10;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else {
            brojTiketa = 10;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        }
    }

    @OnEvent(value = EventConstants.VALUE_CHANGED, component = "drawTip")
    public Object updateDisplay(TipDrawTiketa tipDrawTiketaa) {
        drawTip = tipDrawTiketaa;
        if (drawTip == TipDrawTiketa.LOT_NAC) {
            brojTiketa = 20;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else if (drawTip == TipDrawTiketa.CHANCES) {
            brojTiketa = 10;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else if (drawTip == TipDrawTiketa.NAVIDENA) {
            brojTiketa = 20;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        } else {
            brojTiketa = 20;
            return zonaDjelovanja.getBody();
        }
    }


    /**
     * 
     * @return
     */

    @CommitAfter
    @OnEvent(value = "submit", component = "dodajTiket")
    void onDodajTiket() {
        for (int i = 0; i < brojTiketa; i++) {
            hibernate.save(new Tiket(StringUtils.leftPad(String.valueOf(series + "" + broj), 5, ""), datum, drawTip, String.format("%03d", series), String.format("%02d", broj), status, cijena));

        }
        String redom = "Created ticket sheet  serial   " + series + "\n" + "    number   " + broj;
        //manager.alert(Duration.UNTIL_DISMISSED, Severity.INFO, redom);
        componentResources.discardPersistentFieldChanges();
    }

    @Property
    private JSONObject params;

    @OnEvent(EventConstants.ACTIVATE)
    public void onActivate() {

        params = new JSONObject();

        params.accumulate("modal", true);


    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

On this image, I have tried to use parameter from a field Cantidad de Fracciones which is inside a zone, and it will work only when page is loaded, value of cantidad de fracciones will be changed inside a dialog too, but it's not because of AJAX, I think it gets value of Cantidad de Fracciones from page load and it can't be changed during a stay on this page which is not what I want. I want that value of Cantidad de Fracciones inside dialogbox be updated when I change input inside a field Cantidad de Fracciones.

UPDATE:

Since it's all client-side thing, I have chosen to use JQuery approach as suggested in Lance Java answer and listen on text change of a given fields.

```
<script>
                $("input")
                        .keyup(function() {
                    var value = $(broj).val();
                    $("#provjeraBroj").text(value);
                    var value = $(datum).val();
                    $("#provjeraDatum").text(value);
                    //var value = $(drawTip).val();

                    $('#drawTip').change(function() {
                        var $selected = $(this).find('option:selected');
                        if ($selected.val() === 'LOT_NAC') {
                            $("#provjeraDrawTip").text("Loteri");
                        }
                        if ($selected.val() === 'CHANCES') {
                            $("#provjeraDrawTip").text("Chances");
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#provjeraDrawTip").text("Navideña");

                        }
                    }).change();


                    var value = $(series).val();
                    $("#provjeraSeries").text(value);
                    var value = $(brojTiketa).val();
                    $("#provjeraBrojTiketa").text(value);
                })
                        .keyup();
            </script>
```

Comment: Your "UPDATE" really should be a 2nd answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confirm mixin doesn't generate a dynamic message each time it is invoked clientside. The message is determined serverside as the page is rendered (check the HTML source in your browser and you'll see the message).

So `t:message="¿Seguro que desea crear esta entrada? ${kopijaBroj}"` will render using the initial values of these fields (null and 0).

If you want a dynamic message based on the current field values I can see two options:

1. Use javascript to replace tokens in the message with clientside field values each time the message is displayed.
2. Do a serverside round trip to render the message each time. This will require the current values to be passed serverside using request parameters.

Either way, the confirm mixin doesn't do this out  of the box so you'll need a custom mixin. Option 1 will be a much nicer user experience since its all clientside.

Comment: Thank you on your comment, @Lance. I have used approach number 1 and this can be seen in updated version of my Q. For helping me in direction for where to search for a problem, I choose this answer as accepted.